# No scroll bar in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow, vertical-scrolling

Hey my site works fine except in IE8. The page does not display a vertical scroll bar. I added html { overflow-y :scroll } to the css and only got a scroll bar which does not allow you to actually scroll down. My site is [eagleview.it](http://eagleview.it/)

Thanks very much

Comment: Why do you have your container element set to 'position: fixed'? In fact there are really weird things in your code all over the site. Also, inline-styles?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to fix on IE

```
-ms-overflow-y : scroll;
```

Or this may work as well

```
html {
   height:101%;
}
```